# Incrementing port bits in assembly

Tags: assembly, ports, 8051

As part of a project, I've been asked to write a program to take input from P1 and output it to P2. The obvious method is to just say

```
ORG 000H

MOV C, P1.0
MOV P2.0, C
MOV C, P1.1
MOV P2.1, C
```

...

And so on. But I want to do this with a loop by incrementing the port bits. How would I do that?

Comment: If you just need to take all the bits and forward them to P2, why not read them all at once and write at once?

Comment: I'm new to this, do you mean it's possible to just do something like

MOV P2, P1? 

With a different instruction maybe?

Comment: You can do `MOV C, P1` and then `MOV P2, C` and it'll copy all the bits at once.

Comment: I just asked someone who said that C is too small to hold all of P1. P1 being 8 bits and C 1 bit. Maybe A would be a better choice?

Comment: Sorry, yes, of course not C, but A would work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a 'MOV direct, direct' instruction. In the manual I have OP 0x85 is MOV directly addressed data to a directly addressed location... i.e. MOV P0, P1

Answer (score 2):

The 8051 instruction set does not provide such a bit-move instruction with intermediate source/destination. The `MOV <dest-bit>, <srcibit>` instruction only allows fixed values. See: [8051 MOV instruction](https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/comp/8051/set8051.html#51mov)

You can of course copy the complete (byte) content of P1 to P2 directly. Furthermore the 8051 byte-move instruction does provide an intermediate move via @R1 or @R2 that you could increment in a loop if you'd like to copy multiple ports.